# Opencv Line Length Detection

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I need help with a sample code which is using python language to get the length of vertical and horizontal lines of an uploaded image.

Comment: With *what* sample code? Do you mean you want someone to write it, or help you write it? Note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use cv2.findContours and cv2.approxPolyDP. This will get you a list of rectangles, then you can analyse if they are vertical or horizontal.

Some info: 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Answer (score 0):

Didn't got your question correctly. But here is something according to my understanding.
First, detect the lines:
[Line detection using OpenCV](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/line-detection-python-opencv-houghline-method/)
Second,  use the formula to calculate the distance between two points:
length = norm(p2 - p1)
where p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2)
Note: It will calculate length in pixels.